# Is it possible to pass variables or object's attributes to a function or method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example consider a following function and class:

```
def foo(Atributes,values):
    for item,value in zip(Attributes,values):
        item=value

class bar:
    foo=foo
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
    def update(self,a,b):
        foo((self.a,self.b),(a,b))
```

the above function is just to update the attributes of any objects of class bar. Or more specifically, the function foo is any generalized function to update the attributes of any class other than bar which may have different number of attributes to their objects.
So, is it possible to pass attributes not their value to that generalized function? Or is there any other method to do so: make an generalized function that updates the attributes of any objects of of any class type:

Comment: Attributes themselves, that is a dotted name ``a.b``, are *not* first-class. There are various gotchas to this, such as ``a.b`` potentially being unsymmetric, transient, and/or dynamic, making ``a.b`` by itself ill-defined. Are you looking for ``setattr(a, 'b', ...)`` perhaps?

Comment: i actually have large no of classes and every classes have a method update which updates the attributes of its instance and the attributes are not simply 2, but more. And the update variables are dynamic i.e. all variables may not be updated at a time. So the function must guaranty to update the attributes that are passed as keyword arguments.

Comment: Why use attributes on instances, then, and not just dictionaries? Variadic keyword arguments are already dictionaries, and it is easy to ``.update`` one dictionary by another.

Comment: I also have that using dictionaries in my mind but little confused whether is it efficient in terms of computing time and memory to use dictionary or just bunch of attributes.

Comment: By default, attributes are stored as dictionaries. So dictionaries are roughly as efficient as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Python are basically dictionaries. You **could** do something like this

```
def foo(obj, attributes, values):
    for item, value in zip(attributes,values):
        obj.__dict__[item] = value


class Bar:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

bar = Bar(1, 2)
foo(bar, ["a", "b"], [3, 4])
assert bar.a == 3
assert bar.b == 4
```

That being said: Just because you could, does not mean you should. This solution is hacky, confusing and really not necessary. In nearly all cases it would be better to just set a bunch of member variables:

```
bar.a = 3
bar.b = 4
```

If the fields themself are dynamic in their naming, it would be best just use a dict directly.

Edit: @MisterMiyagi is absolutely correct. You should use setattr(obj, item, value) instead of my even worse hack.

Comment: Note that ``obj.__dict__`` is not guaranteed to be well-defined, e.g. when using ``__slots__``. Use ``setattr(obj, item, value)`` instead.

Comment: i actually have large no of classes and every classes have a method update which updates the attributes of its instance and the attributes are not simply 2, but more. And the update variables are dynamic i.e. all variables may not be updated at a time. So the function must guaranty to update the attributes that are passed as keyword arguments. And this solution does not seem appropriate.

Comment: Just because you could, does not mean you should: this sentence really made my day.